# OneLogin API credentials

Tags: api, curl, credentials, onelogin

Im trying to make a basic call to the ONELOGIN API. After generating the cliend ID and secret with MANAGE ALL permissions, im still unable to connect

Generated correctly the ID and secret with the right permissions as per official documentation

curl 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/token' \
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: client_id:, client_secret:" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "grant_type":"client_credentials"
}'

i expected to connect, instaead the output is

{"status":{"error":true,"code":401,"type":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication Failure"}}

Comment: is the "Authorization: " header really supposed to end with `:` ? i don't think so (i don't know, but it looks really weird)

Comment: Im sorry, i just skipped the values that should be after client_id and client_secret for security purposes. This is what i meant:       curl 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/auth/oauth2/v2/token' \ -X POST \ -H "Authorization: client_id:<client_id_value>, client_secret:<client-secret_value>" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -d '{ "grant_type":"client_credentials" }'

Comment: Don't believe the docs. The format for the client ID for the API is: client_id:123kkjk.....etc, client_secret:adsad123....etc

Comment: So not base64 encoded. In that format exactly, as a string in the Authorization header.