# Is there a Rest API that gets all user from an OIDC onelogin application?

Tags: openid-connect, onelogin

I am unable to access users for an OpenId-Connect OneLogin application.

I have used this Rest API shown at https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/create-user.

curl 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users' \
-X GET \
-H "Authorization: bearer:"

I expect the output to get all users with their names and their email as json field. I keep getting 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: Check your authorization header. Check this post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445306/onelogin-api-credentials

Comment: Does the token need to be Base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token ? No. Send the client id and secret in the authorization header as shown. Get the set of tokens ( including the access token ) in the response. Use the access token from the response in the Authorization header for the Get Users API. As below:

curl -X GET \
  https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: bearer:e2ad283e47a500100cc8ded37a48ff6d8'

Make double sure your API endpoint is correct. If your Onelogin tenant is in the US, us the US API endpoint. If it's in Europe, use the EU endpoint.